# Add a quote Button to bootstrap Navigation Bar and Make it stay Permanently?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like:

```
1. The Free Quote Button to be forced right
2. At small screensizes I would like free quote button to remain to the right of the (icon bar button [mobile menu])
3. I don't want the navigation bar to take up an extra line when at smaller screen size
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/z7V4F/

HTML:

```
<!-- Nav bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navi-style" role="navigation">
    <!-- quote button-->
    <!--<a href="#" class="btn btn-default navbar-right">Free Quote</a>-->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">  <span class="sr-only"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>   <a class="navbar-brand menulogo" href="#">
                My Site + Logo Makes This Long
            </a>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <!--<li class="active"><a href="/index">Home</a></li>-->
            <li class="dropdown">   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Info Tab<b class="caret"></b></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Overview</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">contact Tab<b class="caret"></b></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Overview</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">about Tab<b class="caret"></b></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Overview</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">More Tab<b class="caret"></b></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Overview</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <div class="navbar-right">  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Free Quote</a>

            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Custom Css. As long as you dont add it to the list items of your menu, it should always appear. Look at the code for your menu logo to gain a better understanding for this. Use @media queries with the sizes of your screen to correspondend your needs. Happy testing

Comment: I cleaned up the fiddle a bit http://jsfiddle.net/Eb7Ba/1/ (simply markup formatting)

Comment: @ZachSaucier, nothing to add? then move on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. The Free Quote Button to be forced right**

I would use position: absolute; here to avoid excessive juggling with margins and paddings. This way it will always stay on the same line. This will look worse if your navbar-header and nav items are wider though than in your fiddle.

```
.navbar-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

**2. At small screensizes I would like free quote button to remain to the right of the (icon bar button [mobile menu])**

Put another `<button>` above the navbar-toggle with `pull-right` and `visible-xs` classes. This will place the button on the right side of the navbar-toggle and make it visible only on XS screen sizes.

```
    <div class="pull-right visible-xs free-quote"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Free Quote</a></div>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button> 
    <a class="navbar-brand menulogo" href="#">
        My Site + Logo Makes This Long
    </a>
```

Give hidden-xs class to the other button so It won't show up in XS screen sizes. (example in answer to number 3)

**3. I don't want the navigation bar to take up an extra line when at smaller screen size**

You can show smaller button on SM screen sizes to avoid the **need** for navbar to expand on two lines like this (by need I mean otherwise it is more likely that navigation items and the button will overlap each other):

```
<div class="navbar-right hidden-xs free-quote"> 
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-default visible-sm">Free Quote</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default hidden-sm">Free Quote</a>
</div>
```

I would suggest that you show logo or text only in navbar-brand on XS screen sizes so that they won't jump to their own line when the screen size is only e.g. 320px wide.

**4. Extra: Make it look nice**

Give some padding and margin to those buttons to align them nicely.

```
.free-quote {
    padding: 9px 5px 9px 0
}
.free-quote > .btn-xs {
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z7V4F/3/

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two buttons.

One within the `navbar-header` and one outside.

The `button` within the `navbar-header` should only be visible at the extra small screens, as **everything not within `navbar-header` is hidden at `xs`**.
**Everything within `navbar-collapse` will be hidden (become a mobile menu) at extra small sizes.**

**Html**:

```
 <div class="menuquote navbar-right hidden-xs"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default navbar-right centre-block gr-btn">Free Quote</a>

    </div>
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">  <span class="sr-only"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>   <a class="navbar-brand menulogo" href="#">
                My Site + Logo Makes This Long
            </a>

        <div class="menuquote navbar-right pull-right hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default navbar-right">Free Quote</a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4nmzh/

Answer (score 0):

To get the button to be forced left and to appear to the right of the mobile menu toggle, put this div:

```
 <div class="navbar-right">  
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Free Quote</a>
 </div>
```

just before the `navbar-header` and change `navbar-right` to `pull-right`

This takes the button out of the navbar formatting and forces the button to the right as `pull-right` is bootstrap's `float: right` class.

To stop your navbar going on to two lines at very small screen sizes your options are:

1. Set a `min-width` on your `<nav class="navbar">`

   ```
   .navbar { 
      min-width: 470px; 
   }
   ```

   (see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Eb7Ba/2/))
2. Shrinking the size of your logo/text in your `<a class="navbar-brand">` at small screen sizes using media queries e.g.:

   ```
   @media (max-width: 500px) {
       navbar-brand {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```

When your navbar is larger I have reduced the padding on the list items to make them stay on one line:

```
ul.nav li a {
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}
```

This [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Eb7Ba/2/) should at least give you a starting point.

Comment: I think you should also explain the use of css in this, with just this button the trick wont do, or at least not in the fashion he/she desires. Although this is a good startpoint. Not understanding the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can move free quotes outside the  tag and add absolute position to it
look at the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z7V4F/4/

As I said i moved div containing free quotes outside navbar-collapse and added next css.

```
.custum-free-quotes{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top: 0;
}
.navbar{
    position relative;
}
```