# Why is the circle not round bootstrap and fontawesome?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why is the Circle not Round?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="service-box">
            <h3>MotorCycle Repair</h3>
            <i class="fa service-icon fa-wrench"></i>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View Details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.service-box {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 0 0px 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.service-box:hover {
    background-color: #3fb1fc;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background: #FFD600;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.service-box:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

.service-box a {
    color: #0286F4;
}

.service-box:hover .service-icon {
    border-color: #3fb1fc;
    color: #3fb1fc;
    border: 4px solid #ffd600;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #fff !important;
    background: #fff !important;
    color: #ffd600;
}

.service-box .service-icon {
    width: 80px;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    padding: 25px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffd600;
    color: #fff;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #ffd600;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #3fb1fc;
    background-color: #3fb1fc;
}
```

JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/E3jZ8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `service-icon` class. Width must be `120px` because you have padding of `20px`. Old width was `80px`, so 80-20-20 (padding left and right) = `40px`

So width was `40px` and height was `80px`, with border-radius of 50% it was ellipse;

Right `.service-icon`:

```
.service-box .service-icon {
    width: 120px;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 70px;
    margin: 15px auto;
    padding: 25px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #ffd600;
    color: #fff;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #ffd600;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #3fb1fc;
    background-color: #3fb1fc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aleksandar, please check my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24897834/add-a-quote-button-to-bootstrap-navigation-bar-and-make-it-stay-permanently

Answer (score 1):

Make this change:

```
.service-box .service-icon {
    width: 130px;
    height: 130px;
}
```

Updated JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/E3jZ8/1/